# installing igraph in R failed

Tags: r, linux, igraph

I have R 3.4.1 on Linux Mint (platform i686-pc-linux-gnu), but the same problem happens with a previous version of R and on Windows as well. When I try to install `igraph` using `install.packages()`, this error happens:

```
foreign-graphml.c: In function ‘igraph_write_graph_graphml’:
foreign-graphml.c:1408:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI’
   ret=fprintf(outstream, "<graphml xmlns=\"" GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI "\"\n");
                                              ^
foreign-graphml.c:1412:59: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI’
   ret=fprintf(outstream, "         xsi:schemaLocation=\"" GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI "\n");
                                                           ^
foreign-graphml.c:1414:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI’
   ret=fprintf(outstream, "         " GRAPHML_NAMESPACE_URI "/1.0/graphml.xsd\">\n");
                                      ^
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'foreign-graphml.o' failed
make: *** [foreign-graphml.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/home/ninja/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/igraph’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried installing from github as well, using something along those lines:

```
install_github("igraph/rigraph")
```

The second option works just fine, but installs `igraph 1.1.0`. What I need is 1.1.2, the version I would get with `install.packages()`.

Any other options?

Comment: Well, apparently, there was a bug... https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/213

Answer (score 5):

Just google-ed a solution, which helped me solve this.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

before running `install.packages('igraph')`

Comment: Was helpfull enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the libxml is not the latest version.
For centos, run

```
yum install libxml2-devel
```

then
`install.packages('igraph')`
And it worked for me.